# Mongo query (with positional operator) does not work in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given a database collection with orchards, one object looks like this:

```
{
"orchardId" : ObjectId("5391c137722b051908000000"),
"trees" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "apple",
        "fruits" : []
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "pear",
        "fruits" : [ 
            ObjectId("54c54291d93236150f00004e"), 
            ObjectId("54c542c9d93236150f000062")
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to dynamically add a fruit to a specific tree. I know I can do this in mongo with:

```
db.orchards.update(
    ({"orchardId": ObjectId("5391c137722b051908000000")},
    {"trees" : { $elemMatch: {"name":"apple"}}}),
    { $push: { "trees.$.fruits": ObjectId("54c542c9d900000000001234") }}
)
```

So, if I'm right this should be this in mongoose:

```
orchards.update(
    ({"orchardId": ObjectId.fromString(orchard.id)},
    {"trees" : {$elemMatch: {"name": "apple"}}}),
    {$push: {"trees.$.fruits": ObjectId("54c542c9d900000000001234") }},function(err, data){ ...
```

But then I get an error saying: [TypeError: Cannot call method 'path' of undefined]

It looks like mongoose can't handle the positional operator (the `$`) because when I change the $ with a 0 it does work.

How do I make this work in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample you've got parens where you should have braces, so it should be like this instead:

```
orchards.update({
    "orchardId": ObjectId(orchard.id),
    "trees": {$elemMatch: {"name": "apple"}}
  },
  {$push: {"trees.$.fruits": ObjectId("54c542c9d900000000001234") }},
  function(err, data){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer JohnnyHK!   You can combine objects, and that's what I did there. So the parens are correct. BUT: I figured out that this works in mongoose 3.8.22 but NOT in version 3.6.15 (the one I was using in the first place)

Comment: When you put two objects in parens that will evaluate to just the second object. At least that's what happened when I tried your code.