# Update $inc with Mongoose other behavior then MongoDB update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to update a document with mongoose and it fails. The query I can successful execute directly in Mongo is like:

```
db.orders.update(
    { 
        orderId: 1014428,
        'delivery.items.id': '5585d77c714a90fe0fc2fcb4' 
    },
    {
        $inc: {
            "delivery.items.$.quantity" : 1
        }
    }
)
```

When I try to run the following update command with mongoose:

```
this.update(
        {
            orderId: this.orderId ,
            "delivery.items.id": product.id
        },
        {
            $inc: {
                "delivery.items.$.quantity" : 1
            }
        }, function (err, raw) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
        }
    );
```

I see the following error:

```
{ [MongoError: cannot use the part (items of delivery.items.id) to traverse the element ({items: [ { quantity: 1, price: 6.9, name: "Manipulationstechniken", brand: null, id: "5585d77c714a90fe0fc2fcb4" } ]})]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'cannot use the part (items of delivery.items.id) to traverse the element ({items: [ { quantity: 1, price: 6.9, name: "Manipulationstechniken", brand: null, id: "5585d77c714a90fe0fc2fcb4" } ]})',
  index: 0,
  code: 16837,
  errmsg: 'cannot use the part (items of delivery.items.id) to traverse the element ({items: [ { quantity: 1, price: 6.9, name: "Manipulationstechniken", brand: null, id: "5585d77c714a90fe0fc2fcb4" } ]})' }
The raw response from Mongo was  { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

I tried so many things. Any advice on this?

As requested the schema:

```
var Order = new Schema({
    orderId: Number,
    orderDate: String,
    customerName: String,
    state: Number,
    delivery: {
         items: {type: Array, default: []},
         state: { type: Number, default: 0 }
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked fine when I tried it. What's `this` in the `this.update` call?

Comment: "this" is inside a model function, so this is from the model - in this case Order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** use your model `Order` instead of an instance `this` when doing more advanced queries:

```
Orders.update(
    {
        orderId: this.orderId ,
        "delivery.items.id": product.id
    },
    {
        $inc: {
            "delivery.items.$.quantity" : 1
        }
    }, function (err, raw) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
    }
);
```

---

Explanation:

Mapping differences between `Model.update()` and `Document.update()`.

The using the model, then [Model.update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) will be used and

```
Model.update(conditions, doc, options, callback)
```

will be mapped to:

```
db.collection.update(query = conditions, update = doc, options)
```

---

When using an instance instead your calling [Document.update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) and

```
Document.update(doc, options, callback)
```

will be mapped to the following:

```
db.collection.update(query = {_id: _id}, update = doc, options)
```

Comment: Would great if it works, unfortunately I ran into to following error trying the code: 

TypeError: Object #<Schema> has no method 'update'
    at model.Order.methods.addProductToDelivery (/Users/kl3tte/development/st/models/order.js:149:15)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/kl3tte/development/st/routes/order.js:120:27)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/kl3tte/development/st/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:175:45)

Comment: Then in your case Orders is only your Schema... You will get a model with `mongoose.model('Orders', Orders)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157681/mongo-query-with-positional-operator-does-not-work-in-mongoose) the O.P. had a similar issue with mongoose 3.6.15, and claimed it was solved in 3.8.22

EDIT: In the linked question, the O.P. had the following working on mongodb

```
db.orchards.update(
({"orchardId": ObjectId("5391c137722b051908000000")},
{"trees" : { $elemMatch: {"name":"apple"}}}),
{ $push: { "trees.$.fruits": ObjectId("54c542c9d900000000001234") }})
```

But this not working in mongoose:

```
orchards.update(
({"orchardId": ObjectId.fromString(orchard.id)},
{"trees" : {$elemMatch: {"name": "apple"}}}),
{$push: {"trees.$.fruits": ObjectId("54c542c9d900000000001234") }},function(err, data){ ...
```

In a comment, he said the issue was solved switching to mongoose 3.8.22

Comment: I currently use mongoose 4.0.5

Comment: Thanks for advise, done. However, Tobias is using 4.0.5, so this may not be the solution for him